# Use twice DISTINCT ON ina multiple join situation

Tags: postgresql, query, postgresql-10

I'm using PostgreSQL 10. I have an entity `Product`.

The product has images, so I have a `Foreign key` from `Product to Image`.

A `Product` have `1 ON 1 relationship`, with a `Video` entity

A product can have multiple categories and a category can have multiple products, so I have `M2M relationship` from `Product` to `Category`

```
--- Product ---
id | name | 

--- Image ---
id | image | product_id

--- Video ---
id | channel | url |product_id

--- CategoryProduct ---
id | category_id |product_id

--- Category ---
id | name
```

I need to get a list of Product(s) with their first/one Image and Video and also the first Category

I use `DISTINCT ON` to get just one image, in the query bellow:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(p.id)  p.id,  p.name, i.image, coalesce(v.channel, v.url) as video 
                  FROM product AS p
                  INNER JOIN  image as i on p.id = i.product_id 
                  LEFT JOIN video as v on p.id = v.product_id"
```

My issue is how do I get also the first Category for the Product ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly a product can have more than one image/video an of course more than one category.

In this case you can use a [LATERAL JOIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) and limit the result to only one row.

I've set up one small fiddle just to show you:

> ```
> select p.id,
>        p.name,
>        i.image,
>        v.channel,
>        v.url,
>        c.name
> from   products p
> left join lateral (select id, image
>                    from   image
>                    where  product_id = p.id
>                    limit  1) i on true
> left join lateral (select id, channel, url
>                    from video
>                    where product_id = p.id
>                    limit 1) v on true
> left join lateral (select c.id, c.name 
>                    from   categoryproduct cp
>                    join   category c
>                    on     cp.category_id = c.id
>                    where  cp.product_id = p.id
>                    limit 1) c on true;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name  | image | channel | url  | name
> -: | :---- | :---- | :------ | :--- | :---
>  1 | prod1 | img1  | c1      | url1 | cat1
>  2 | prod2 | img3  | c3      | url3 | cat3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f2545dedbabe7c0c2cf4cfbd7298fd9a)*